# How to make this Spring Injection work

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, spring, spring-mvc

I have this inside my spring xml file:

```
<object type="Test.Web.Utilities.TestClass, Test.Web" singleton="false" id="TestClass">
    <property name="TestService" ref="TestService"/>
</object>
```

In the TestClass I have this:

```
public ITestService TestService { get; set; }
```

and this:

```
public void TestMethod()
{
var x = TestService.ExampleMethod();
}
```

next, inside my controller I have this:

```
TestClass t = new TestClass();
t.TestMethod();
```

However, I don't seem to get this to work. other spring related stuff on the controller works well.

Any ideas how can I get this to work?

**EDIT:** Forgot to add, the error I get is a NullReferenceException

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This cannot work since you're creating TestClass instance via **new** and Spring is of course not aware to inject dependencies into objects created via the frameworks new. You'll not find a .NET IOC framework that can do this (for good reasons!).

So what you need to do is to inject instances of TestClass into your controller. You could register these instances with a request or prototype scope.

Comment: Hi, do you mean that I should do this: public ITestClass TestClass { get; set; }, something like that?

Comment: Yes, use property or constructor injection

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use the normal "new" keyword, because this is handled via the .NET VM.  You actually need to call Spring's Activator Context to give you an instance.

First you acquire the Spring.NET Activator context by calling:

```
IApplicationContext ctx = ContextRegistry.GetContext();
```

Then you can get an instance of your class specified in your configuration xml:

```
ITestService svc = (ITestService)ctx.GetObject("TestClass");
```

This enables you to configure via your XML file what concrete implementation class that implements the ITestService interface.